# my cpu is currently runnind on 100% when no more process is running, I will add three screenshots of my system it will help you to help me

Tags: cpu

Resource Monitor:

[image: First Image]

Storage Usage;

[image: Second Image]

Process List:

[image: Third Image]

Comment: You have not told us which distro and version of Linux you are using. You have not told us what you did before facing this problem. Did you install something? Did you change some settings? Did you try some new command? Did you run some `code` or scripts? [Update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1393268/edit) with written description of the problem including precise information about what you did before. Just pictures are not enough.

Comment: Looks like two VSCode instances are still running in the background...